# Flutter: How to access User Data from several Screens?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform

I am currently working on getting my user data from Firebase. And since I need this data on several screens (e.g. I need to display the name and email of my user on 4 different screens), I thought of a more efficient way I could do that. Currently I am just sending a request to firebase to get the user data. But I am doing this for every single screen where I need the username or e-mail.

Therefore I thought I would setup a user class which does that. So now I want to get the name and email adress from the currently logged in user from the User class (which gets it from firebase), instead of having the lines of code which request the data from firebase for every single screen. How can I do that now? How could the code look for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may try to use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package by Flutter and set a class for user. So, in that case you would just set up functions to check if user is logged in, and if yes, you could do other actions.

Comment: I am already doing it. That is not my point. My point is how do I get the name, email and other user data from firestore and save it in a user class, so I can access it from all my screens instead of doing the request for every single screen?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it, but I would use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to get the Auth service you created. In Auth service you may put all your code related to login, register and function to check if user is logged in. Then you can use that Auth in your code like

```
final user = Provider.of<UserModels>(context);
```

I am not sure if you have Auth service, if you do, you may update your question with your code to get more help.

Another option would be to use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to get the boolean value if user is logged in or not, but still it would apply provider there.